# How to implement bit-shift in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker, bit-shift

I'm working on captcha, but the server doesn't support php and i can't add java libraries to it. So I have to implement check on freemarker, but the function using binary shift `<<`, is it any way to implement it in freemarker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there's no binary arithmetic in Freemarker out-of-the-box. (Of course, all binary operations can be implemented with the four basic operators, but it would be rather perverse to do... Though shift left with `* 2` and `%` doesn't sound that bad.)

Comment: The conditions, in which I need to use left shift imply that number should become negative, when it come to the highest bit, but there no highest bit in freemarker. Fo, that's a problem. But I have done it other way, thanks.